# CUDA & PhysX in Windows on Unibody Macbook '09

Tags: windows, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

How can I get CUDA and PhysX hardware acceleration to work on Unibody Macbook from late 2009? Despite having 9400M which is listed as having support for CUDA on NVIDIA's site, I'm unable to run any PhysX demos in anything but software mode.

I have downloaded the non-Apple-approved "notebook" drivers from NVIDIA to no avail. Filename: `195.62_notebook_winxp_32bit_international_whql.exe`.

Is there an option I am supposed to turn on somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Figured this out by myself](http://blog.vucica.net/2010/02/unibody-macbook-2009-nvidia-9400m.html), some time ago.

9400m has 16 CUDA cores, therefore not supporting PhysX. However, if you install older drivers, you can get *some* acceleration because they don't check how many CUDA cores you have. Try [9.09.0408 drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/object/physx_9.09.0408_whql.html).

However it looks like 32 CUDA cores, as specified in newer drivers by NVIDIA, is a reasonable minimum, because the acceleration I got for the NVIDIA's fluids demo and for Great Kulu demo was minimal.